# R: How to separate out selected choices in a select all that apply question

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a select all that apply question in a survey asking why someone is leaving their job. I want to make a bar chart that shows the number of times each response option was selected. However, R is treating all of the selected options from each respondent as one column/variable separated by commas for each response option. I've attached an image of what this looks like. How can I create a basic bar chart separating out the response options when the data are formatted in this way? Any thoughts are appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created some mock data. Use strsplit to split out the values separated by commas. This creates a list so you can use unlist to create a vector. In ggplot I flipped the coordinates because you have some values with long names which might work better with this orientation.

```
data <- data.frame(Q8 =c("a", "a,b", "a,c", "c,d,e", "a,b,e"))

data.frame(Q8 = unlist(strsplit(data$Q8, ","))) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Q8)) +
    geom_bar() +
    coord_flip()
```

[image: s]

Comment: @Mark217 - if happy with the response, please consider marking it as the correct answer. :-)